# Issue with passing the data in Vue / EventBus

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, event-bus

I have an issue that I do not understand regarding passing data in Vue.

In store I have the following data (six categories - wine, beer, whiskey, gin, vodka and rum):

```
state: {
        shopItems: [
            {
                id: 1,
                category: "wine",
                price: 20,
                image:
                    "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//Z",
                items: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: "Ruby",
                        price: 17,
                        image:
                            "https://images.freshop.com/1564405684707189696/e52a7445e17de485c0ae890de8762d57_medium.png"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: "Sauvignon Blanc",
                        price: 23,
                        image:
                            "https://ipcdn.freshop.com/resize?url=https://images.freshop.com/00898322593368/2e0ad0dbe0ef46eded5590acdf43cae5_large.png&width=256&type=webp&quality=40"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        name: "Dark Horse",
                        price: 25,
                        image:
                            "https://ipcdn.freshop.com/resize?url=https://images.freshop.com/00085000024218/680b13803f3203f3117eb69082f95cc2_large.png&width=256&type=webp&quality=40"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        name: "Andree",
                        price: 35,
                        image:
                            "https://ipcdn.freshop.com/resize?url=https://images.freshop.com/00085000008287/17d49b2b92223defb638ca7b535dbab3_large.png&width=256&type=webp&quality=40"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                category: "beer",
                price: 3,
                image:
                    "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxIQEhAQEg8TFhEXExYSGRcVFRYSEhYVGBUYGBUVFRYcAAEAAgIDAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgcEBQEDCAL/",
                items: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: "Banana",
                        price: 5,
                        image:
                            "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxAQDxIPEhIPFRAPEhcPEBYSEBgSDw8QFRIS0tLS0uLi0tLS8tLS8tLi0tLS0tLi0tLS8tLS0wLS0tLS0tLS0tLSstLf/AABEIAOEA4QMBEQACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAEAAgIDAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQYEBwECCAP/"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: "Franziskaner Weissbier",
                        price: 6,
                        image:
                            "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxIQEhAQEg8TFhEXExYSGRcVFRYSEhYVGBUDEQH/xAAcAAEAAgIDAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgcEBQEDCAL/xABIEAACAgECAgcEBwQFCgcAAAAAAQIDEQQhBRIGBxMiMUFRYXGBwRQjMnKRobFCUpLCJDNigtE0Q1 "
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        name: "Birra Moretti",
                        price: 5,
                        image:
                            "data:image/jpeg; QQFEiExBgcTIkFRYXGBFCMycpGhsdEkM0JSYsE1Q1OCkhUWJTREVIOTotLh8PH/xAAaAQEAAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMEAQUG/8QANBEBAAICAAQDBQcEAgMAAAAAAAECAxEEEiExE0FRBSIyYXGBkaGxwdHwFEJS4SPxFTOC/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDuMBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQNHau1adKoe59wE7q91mLN5BVBJ+ "
                    }
                ]
            },
```

.
.
.

In my application I am passing the data related to the index of the chosen category from ToBeBought component to ShowDetails component – using EventBus.

```
showDetails(item) {
            console.log("@item.category");
            console.log(item.category);
            const chosenCategoryIndex = this.shopItems.findIndex(
                i => i.category === item.category
            );
            // const chosenCategoryItems = this.shopItems[chosenCategoryIndex]
            //     .items;
            console.log("@chosenCategoryIndex");
            console.log(chosenCategoryIndex);
            EventBus.$emit("chosenCategory", chosenCategoryIndex);
            this.$router.push("/details");
```

I pass the index of the chosen category - e.g. for wine index is 0.
I run chosenCategoryItems method on mounted
(I tried running it on created as well but it did not help)
to get the data in ShowDetails component. In console.log from this method I get an array with detailed data e.g. wines but after that method in mounted I have another console log to show the array (console.log(this.detailedItemsToBeBought);) - I get undefined from it.
It looks like the data was cleared in the meantime - I do not get what is going on here.
I tried to add watcher on detailedItemsToBeBought data but it is not being triggered.

```
data() {
    return {
        itemsToBeBought: [],
        detailedItemsToBeBought: []
    };
},

mounted() {
    this.chosenCategoryItems();
    console.log("@detailedItemsToBeBought mounted");
    console.log(this.detailedItemsToBeBought);
    console.log("@this.shopItems[0].items");
    console.log(this.shopItems[0].items);
},

methods: {
        chosenCategoryItems() {
            EventBus.$on("chosenCategory", data => {
                const chosenCategoryIndex = data;
                console.log("@chosenCategoryIndex");
                console.log(chosenCategoryIndex);
                this.detailedItemsToBeBought = this.shopItems[
                    chosenCategoryIndex
                ].items;
                console.log("@detailedItemsToBeBought event bus");
                console.log(this.detailedItemsToBeBought);
            });
            return this.detailedItemsToBeBought;
        }
```

When I try to display the data I do not see anything but when hardcode this.shopItems[0].items I get the data I need - e.g. for wine category the array with wines;

I know it is not an easy issue but is anyone able and willing to take the challenge to explain me whot might had gone wrong here. Why I get the data from this.shopItems[0].items but when I pass index to this.detailedItemsToBeBought = this.shopItems[chosenCategoryIndex].items; - it works fine in the method chosenCategoryItems but after that the data this.detailedItemsToBeBought are   undefined on mounted?

I attach screenshot from console.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/30rk7.png

and the whole repository:
https://github.com/agnesliszka/alcohol_shop

Comment: (1) if you are using `vuex` , you do need to use `EventBus`. You can access global state in any component (2) Still if you want to use `eventBus`, both `listener` and `emitter` components have to present in the DOM. say data emits from component `A' on button click, and you redirecting to component `B' and `listener` you have in component `B', it wont work. In this case component 'B' hasn't loaded in DOM, hence cant listen to any `eventbus`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your component needs to register for the listener BEFORE you emit the event.

You might want to simply store the chosen category in the store, instead of using an event.

If you really want to use an event (not recommended), you can delay the emit until after the component is ready, using `nextTick` or `setTimer`.

You will also want to register the listener in `created` or `mounted`.

```
this.$nextTick(()=>{
 EventBus.$emit("chosenCategory", chosenCategoryIndex);
})
this.$router.push("/details");
```